# Agregar logo en programa de python

Tags: python, pyqt4

estoy haciendo un programa con PyQt4 ya está terminado, solo necesito agregarle mi logo, cómo podría hacerlo sólo con el código?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Priscilla, bienvenida. En dónde quieres que aparezca el logo, y de que forma (ícono, una ventana emergente, otro)?

Comment: Hola, el programa esta hecho en PyQt4, lo que en realidad necesito es modificar una cuadrícula pero nadie me ha logrado ayudar con eso entonces desarrollé la cuadrícula en photoshop y la quiero poner en jpg como si fuese un logo detrás de la gráfica, eso es lo que necesito.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432637/pyqt4-set-windows-taskbar-icon

Answer (score 0):

Alguna vez, hice una aplicación que tenía lo que llaman un "splash", como pantalla de bienvenida:

> La clase **Ventana** es una ventana WX, y hace las veces de logo, mientras que **MiPrograma**, es la ventana (tkinter) del programa principal.
>   La imágen es un archivo gif estático.

[image: unlogo.gif]

```
import wx
from tkinter import Tk, Label

class MiPrograma():
    def __init__(self):
        ven = Tk()
        ven.geometry("400x100+100+100")
        ven.title("Soy el programa principal")
        Label(ven, text="Oh, si").pack()

class Ventana(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Con forma",
                          style=wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR | wx.SIMPLE_BORDER | wx.FRAME_SHAPED)
        imagen = wx.Image("unlogo.gif", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_GIF)
        imagen.SetMaskColour(255,255,255)
        imagen.SetMask(True)
        self.fondo = wx.Bitmap(imagen)

        self.ancho = imagen.GetWidth()
        self.alto = imagen.GetHeight()

        self.SetClientSize((self.fondo.GetWidth(), self.fondo.GetHeight()))
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.fondo, 0, 0, True)
        self.SetWindowShape()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.pintar)

        wx.CallLater(2000, self.Destroy)

    def SetWindowShape(self, evt=None):
        region = wx.Region(self.fondo)
        self.SetShape(region)
        x_imagen = int((wx.Display(0).GetGeometry().GetSize()[0] / 2) - (self.ancho /2))
        y_imagen = int((wx.Display(0).GetGeometry().GetSize()[1] / 2) - (self.alto /2))
        self.Move(x_imagen,y_imagen)


    def pintar(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.fondo, 0, 0, True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    v = Ventana()
    v.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
    mp = MiPrograma()
```

Dentro de la clase **Ventana**, al final del **init**, se encuentra la instrucción que hace que la ventana del logo se cierre automáticamente luego de 2.000 milisegundos

> wx.CallLater(2000, self.Destroy)

Comment: Hola, el programa esta hecho en PyQt4, lo que en realidad necesito es modificar una cuadrícula pero nadie me ha logrado ayudar con eso entonces desarrollé la cuadrícula en photoshop y la quiero poner en jpg como si fuese un logo detrás de la gráfica, eso es lo que necesito.